# Refinery - Mathematical formulation of problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

In a refinery, two types of crude oil $T_1, T_2$ get mixed with two different procedures $R$ and $W$ and produce two types of petrol $P_1, P_2$ as shown at the following matrix:

$\begin{matrix}
\text{Procedure} & \text{Entrance (crude oil)} & \text{Outlet (petrol)}  \\ 
 & T_1 \ \ T_2 &  P_1 \ \ P_2 \\ 
R & 6 \ \ 4& 5 \ \ 2  \\ 
W & 3 \ \ 5 &   2 \ \ 4
\end{matrix}$

The available quantities of crude oil of type $T_1, T_2$ are $180$ and $200$ units respectively.

The requirements of the market impose the production of at least $100$ units of petrol of each type.The profit per  cycle of production is $2$ and $3$ units respectively for the procedures $R$ and $W$. What is needed is the determination of the number of cycles of production from each procedure that brings the maximum possible profit.

Question:

Is the mathematical formulation of the above problem the following? 
$x_i$ denotes the quantity of $T_i$ that is used.

$$\max (2x_1+3x_2)\\ 6x_1+3x_2=180 \\ 4x_1+5x_2=200 \\ 5x_1+2x_2 \leq 100 \\ 2x_1+4x_2 \leq 100$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to know the number of cycles $R, W$ yield maximum profit, you should let your variable reflect this context; i.e. in your model $x_1$ should correspond to the number of $R$-cycles and $x_2$ to the number of $W$-cycles.
2. The text does not say to use up **all** the available oil, but that is what you formulated in constraints (1) and (2). You should rather use $\leq$.
3. The other two constraints are ok.

Comment: It may be important to add that the values of x1, x2 has to be nonzero positive integers and that "The requirements of the market impose the production of at least 100100 units of petrol of each type."

Comment: @NoChance Could I ask you something? A group of three persons decided to clean buildings. The time, in hours, that a building needs to be cleaned and its remuneration in euros is:

$\begin{matrix}
\text{ Number of roofs } & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1\\ 
\text{ Time of cleaning} & 2 & 1,5 & 1,1 & 0,6\\ 
\text{Remuneration} & 51 & 37 & 27 & 12
\end{matrix}$

The persons work in total till $24$ hours the week.  They have to clean at least $20$ buildings with $1,2$ or $3$ roofs the week. Which is the highest remuneration that they can achieve in one week? $$$$
Is the mathematical formulation the following?

Comment: @NoChance $$\max (12x_1+27x_2+37x_3+51x_4) \\ 0.6x_1+1.1 x_2+1.5 x_3+2x_4 \leq 24 \\ x_1+x_2+x_3 \leq 20 \\ \text{ where } x_i \text{ is the number of buildings with i roofs}$$

Comment: I am not good in this area, I suggest you copy the comment to a new question a more capable person may pick it up.

Comment: Consider reading something like this:https://books.google.ca/books?id=CbFwJLHpX7sC&pg=PA18&dq=linear+programing+problem+formulation+examples+steps&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijvaXoqpjKAhWDtRoKHQtTAlQQ6AEIQTAE#v=onepage&q=linear%20programing%20problem%20formulation%20examples%20steps&f=false

Answer (score 0):

$max\bigl((5p_1 + 2p_2)x_1+(2p_1+4p_2)x_2\bigl)$  $\quad Subject\;to\;the\;constraints$
$6x_1+3x_2\le180$
$4x_1+5x_2\le200$
$5x_1+2x_2\ge100$
$2x_1+4x_2\ge100$ $\quad where \;p_1 \;is\; price\;of\; Fuel\; P_1\; and\; p_2\; is \;price\; of \;Fuel\; P_2$